# How to write the right query to get only needed fields (Nest, MySQL)

Tags: mysql, nest

I have two tables: users and freelancer, which are connected one to one. I'm trying to query data from freelancer table, and I also need one field from users table.

But with this code:

```
.createQueryBuilder('freelancer')
    .leftJoinAndSelect('freelancer.user', 'users')
    .where(`freelancer.userId = ${id}`)
    .getOne()
```

I get all data from users table. I tried to make it in different ways with `leftJoinAndMapOne` but I have errors every time. I can't figure out how to write correctly.

[This is query what I've got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfcPw.png),

[but I need something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1o5pu.png)

Comment: Please post the code and error as text, not images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried inner join if not then try it, and also you are using some dots instead of commas try them

for example you are doing this in your 2nd image that you have shared

```
SELECT freelancer.*,users.email from freelancer left join users on freelancer.userId=users.id;
```

instead you can try it like

```
SELECT f.id,*,u.id,u.email from freelancer f inner join users u on f.userId=u.id;
```

try this and let me know i will update it accordingly

Comment: Thanks. Inner join was helpful, but its not solve my problem. By the way I choosed wrong way at begginig, so now I changed code and it works

Comment: i am glad it worked out, by the way if you want more info i can explain it as well